# ¿Cómo puedo lograr que predominen mis estilos CSS ante las clases de bootstrap?

Tags: css

He tratado de agregar el estilo de `'margin:auto;'` a una imagen y no lo he logrado ya que predominan los estilos de boootstrap, y no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: Deberías poner algo de tu código y que versión de bootstrap usas. Puedes usar `!important` para sobreescribir estilos pero no es bueno abusar de ello, es mejor usar la especificidad de css. Aún así habría que ver que estilo exactamente le está afectando porque si ya tiene un `!important` no te va a quedar otra que usarlo tu también y además usar un selector más específico que el de bootstrap

Comment: Relacionado: [Selector hover de css no funciona después de usar la función animate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40055/selector-hover-de-css-no-funciona-despu%C3%A9s-de-usar-la-funci%C3%B3n-animate/40071#40071)

Comment: Gracias pude solucionar mi problema con la ayuda de ustedes...

Answer (score 6):

Revisa que tu archivo CSS personalizado se encuentre debajo de la llamada al Boostrap.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="css/ **tuestilo** .css" rel="stylesheet">
```

De esa manera se priorizará el estilo que se encuentra más abajo.
Si aún así no cambia, agrega al final de la propiedad "!important". Ejemplo: **margin: auto *!important*;**

Te recomiendo que utilices el inspector de elementos de Firefox para identificar que clases afectan a que elementos.

Comment: Gracias pude solucionar mi problema con la ayuda de ustedes...

Answer (score 4):

Cada vez que quieras que algun estilo predomine colocale la palabra !important despues de la propiedad por ejemplo:

margin: auto !important;

así tomará el que le pusiste !important.

Answer (score 0):

Toma en cuenta que los navegadores leen los sitios desde arriba hacia abajo, por lo que deberás llamar a tu hoja de estilos **después** de las de bootstrap, de esa forma se irán pisando.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias pude solucionar mi problema con la ayuda de ustedes...